# Vertical align text to image in header

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

Link: https://7215y46b21s4r6en-26803830855.shopifypreview.com/

What I'd like to do is make it so the text that appears on top in the dark green bar would appear vertically aligned to the image, and not this weird alignment that I can't figure how I've made...

Here is the html:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 425px){
  #message{font-size:10px;}
  .shippingimage{display:none;}
}
.ShowHide {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #2a4735;
  color: white;
}
#left-showing {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#right-showing {
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.ShowHide a {
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
}
.ShowHide a:hover {
   text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ShowHide" id="Bar">
  <div id="right-showing">
    <a href="#" onclick="Hide(Bar);">X</a>
  </div>
  
  <div id="left-showing">

    <p style="margin-bottom:auto;text-align:center;">
      <span id="message"></span></p>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function nextMsg(index) {
        if (messages.length === index) {
            nextMsg(0);
        } else {
            $('#message').html(messages[index]).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000, ()=> nextMsg(index+1));
        }
    };

    var messages = [
        '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/bcq9ydY.png" width="30px" class="shippingimage"><a href="https://www.fermento24.com/pages/spedizione" style="letter-spacing: -0.5px;vertical-align: super;">Consegna gratuita in giornata a Napoli, Caserta e relative province sopra i 25€</a>',
        '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/pSAQiQp.png" width="35px" class="shippingimage"><a href="https://www.fermento24.com/pages/spedizione" style="vertical-align: super;"> Spedizione gratuita nel resto d’Italia sopra i 120€</a>',
    ];

    $('#message').hide();

    nextMsg(0);
    </script>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your example has an error so we cannot see what you are trying to do

Comment: I added jquery to make the snippet work

Comment: use ```display:flex``` with ```align-iems:center```

Comment: Add `vertical-align: middle` to the `img` tag and remove `vertical-align: super` from the `anchor` tag

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 425px){
  #message{font-size:10px;}
  .shippingimage{display:none;}
}
.ShowHide {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #2a4735;
  color: white;
}
.shippingimage{
  vertical-align: bottom; <- added this
}
#left-showing {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#right-showing {
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
}
.ShowHide a {
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
.ShowHide a:hover {
   text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `vertical-align: super` at the `a` tag and add `vertical-align: middle` at `img` tag should be work.

Example code:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 425px){
  #message{font-size:10px;}
  .shippingimage{display:none;}
}
.ShowHide {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #2a4735;
  color: white;
}
#left-showing {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#right-showing {
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.ShowHide a {
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
}
.ShowHide a:hover {
   text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ShowHide" id="Bar">
  <div id="right-showing">
    <a href="#" onclick="Hide(Bar);">X</a>
  </div>
  <div id="left-showing">
    <p style="margin-bottom:auto;text-align:center;">
      <span id="message"></span>
    </p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function nextMsg(index) {
        if (messages.length === index) {
          nextMsg(0);
        } else {
          $('#message').html(messages[index]).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000, () => nextMsg(index+1));
        }
      };
      var messages = [
        '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/bcq9ydY.png" width="30px" class="shippingimage" style="vertical-align: middle;"><a href="https://www.fermento24.com/pages/spedizione" style="letter-spacing: -0.5px;">Consegna gratuita in giornata a Napoli, Caserta e relative province sopra i 25€</a>',
        '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/pSAQiQp.png" width="35px" class="shippingimage" style="vertical-align: middle;"><a href="https://www.fermento24.com/pages/spedizione"> Spedizione gratuita nel resto d’Italia sopra i 120€</a>',
      ];
      $('#message').hide();
      nextMsg(0);
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - I advise you to use the `flex` rules. Add this to your css:

```
#message{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

2 - Remove `styles` attribute along with styles from this tag `p`:

```
<p style="margin-bottom:auto;text-align:center;">
...
</p>
```

3 - Also, your `span #message` tag gets `display: inline` dynamically. You need to disable this in `javascript` or `jquery`. Or use `!important` for `display: flex` in `#message`:

```
#message{
  display: flex!important;
  ...
}
```

If you follow my answer, then the content of your green header will look nice.

```css
.ShowHide {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #2a4735;
  color: white;
}
#left-showing {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#right-showing {
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.ShowHide a {
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
}
.ShowHide a:hover {
   text-decoration:underline;
}

#message{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 425px){
  #message{font-size:10px;}
  .shippingimage{display:none;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ShowHide" id="Bar">
  <div id="right-showing">
    <a href="#" onclick="Hide(Bar);">X</a>
  </div>
  
  <div id="left-showing">

    <p>
      <span id="message"></span></p>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function nextMsg(index) {
        if (messages.length === index) {
            nextMsg(0);
        } else {
            $('#message').html(messages[index]).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000, ()=> nextMsg(index+1));
        }
    };

    var messages = [
        '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/bcq9ydY.png" width="30px" class="shippingimage"><a href="https://www.fermento24.com/pages/spedizione" style="letter-spacing: -0.5px;vertical-align: super;">Consegna gratuita in giornata a Napoli, Caserta e relative province sopra i 25€</a>',
        '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/pSAQiQp.png" width="35px" class="shippingimage"><a href="https://www.fermento24.com/pages/spedizione" style="vertical-align: super;"> Spedizione gratuita nel resto d’Italia sopra i 120€</a>',
    ];

    $('#message').hide();

    nextMsg(0);
    </script>
</div>
</div>
```